# Punctuation to introduce a list: comma vs. colon vs. nothing

Tags: punctuation, commas, lists, colons

Which of these sentences is written correctly?

> 1. Angela has three brothers, Mark, Adam, and Ryan.
> 2. Angela has three brothers: Mark, Adam, and Ryan.
> 3. Angela has three brothers Mark, Adam, and Ryan

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9343/how-to-punctuate-a-list-of-questions; http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13484/what-punctuation-belongs-before-a-list.

Answer (score 9):

> Angela has three brothers: Mark, Adam, and Ryan.

That's the one to go with.

N.B. This is called the **syntactical-descriptive** function of the colon: it "introduces a description—in particular, makes explicit the elements of a set" (Wikipedia)

Comment: The example with no punctuation is horrible by the way. :D

Comment: The comma before the _and_ really bothers me :|

Comment: It bothers me too, even though I know it is right.

Comment: @Kevin and mplungjan: There's a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/) for that. (^_^)

Comment: @mplungian: That's another issue. But while the "Oxford comma" may bother you, it's at least a negotiable stylistic point.

Comment: I have it on good authority that the "Oxford comma" didn't even go to college.

Comment: Robusto's answer is correct (of course), but just to add another possibility: you could use a dash, and write *Angela has three brothers—Mark, Adam and Ryan.*

Comment: By the way, just saying, I think in italian the last comma would be considered a mistake. I've always known it's like this, I guess I'd need to investigate deeper.

Comment: I was taught to use the comma when continuing a list and to skip it otherwise. A I recall, the example was a written list of people being invited to a party: John, Frank and Nancy, and Susan. John and Susan are singles, Frank and Nancy are a couple. Dropping the last comma in that case would be confusing. Keeping it then but dropping it for "John, Frank, Nancy, and Susan" would be inconsistent at best and confusing at worst. Not that what I was taught carries any weight. My real preference would be to write "Frank & Nancy", thus defusing the whole argument.

Comment: :John, the Sinatras, and Susan?

Answer (score 1):

> Angela has three brothers: Mark, Adam, and Ryan.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please edit your answer to explain *why* it is right and to provide at least one reliable citation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a series of three or more terms with a single conjunction, use a comma after each term except the last.  With only a few exceptions, the serial comma clarifies any ambiguity when the meaning is not as simple as the example above.  Clarity ought to be the objective in writing!